# round multicolor progress bar

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I tried to implement next progress bar in my react app.

[image: round progress bar]

For now, I am using next code

```
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
    var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

    var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

    var d = [
        "M", start.x, start.y, 
        "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
    ].join(" ");

    return d;       
}
```

And generate 2 svg paths one inside of another.
So actually I have this

[image: result]

So, I don't know, how to fix corners problem and need some help.

Generating rounds

```
<circle
                    cx={size / 2}
                    cy={size / 2}
                    r={
                        renderDoubleCircleProgress
                            ? size / 2 - 5 - 9
                            : size / 2 - 5
                    }
                    strokeWidth={
                        thickness
                    }
                    fill='none'
                    className={className}
                />
               
                    <circle
                        cx={size / 2}
                        cy={size / 2}
                        r={size / 2 - 5}
                        strokeWidth={
                            thickness
                        }
                        fill='none'
                        className={className}
                    />
```

Comment: can you show us a snippet with the generated svg as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a properly specified radial gradient - for example

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
<defs>
      <radialGradient id="myGradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="250" cy="250" r="220">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="green" />
      <stop offset="97.5%" stop-color="green" />
      <stop offset="98%" stop-color="cyan" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>

  <path stroke-width="40" d="M100 100 A 200 200 0 0 1 400 400" stroke="url(#myGradient)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
  
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thx! I will try this way,

Answer (score 0):

But you want those rounded corners when you do more than 2 circles:

```html
<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister-with-Progress.min.js"></script>

<progress-circle edge="grey">
  <style>
    svg {
      font: 16px arial;
      height: 220px;
    }
  </style>
  <progress value="75%" stroke="green">SEO</progress>
  <progress value="60%" stroke="orange">Social</progress>
  <progress value="65%" stroke="teal" edge="black">Maps</progress>
  <progress value="50%" stroke="orangered">Traffic</progress>
</progress-circle>
```